# How to use doc package \efill

Tags: indexing, doc

I'm using indexing with the `doc` package and I've run in to an issue. When I have keys that are more than one word they justify over the whole column. I wanted to use the `\efill` macro to get the keys left aligned but keep the numbers right aligned. If I use the `\efill` inside the key the `,` is moved to the right.

I tried reading the package documentation but I can't figure out how to do it.

How can I set it up so that the `\efill` is to the left of the `,` or replace the `,` with the `\efill`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{doc}

\IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}% section heading, no message

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text \index{Spread out} \index{\textbackslash efill\efill}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A rather naïve (and possibly buggy) solution would be to define `\def\argfill#1{#1\efill}` then use `\argfill` instead of `\efill`.

Comment: Wouldn't that look exactly the same as when I use `\efill` above?

Comment: No, because the command `\argfill` will take one argument, which will be the comma. The command then places the comma (`#1`) and then the `\efill` command, making the swap you asked. I posted a few alternatives for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comma is inserted automatically by `makeindex`, so you can't (in an elegant way) put an `\efill` (which, for the record, is `\hfill\nopagebreak`) after the comma in the TeX side of the thing.

I'll give you a few possible solutions, depending on exactly *how* you want to achieve that.

#### If you want that in *all* entries (correct way):

You have to create a custom style file for `makeindex` which automagically prints the `\efill` after the comma. A simple style file which does that is:

```
delim_0    ",\\myfill "
delim_1    ",\\myfill "
delim_2    ",\\myfill "
```

(I used `\myfill` instead of `\efill` so that you can redefine that easily later).

Save that to a file called, say, `flushcomma.ist` and, suppose your `.tex` file is called `mydoc.tex`, compile your document then run `makeindex` with:

```
makeindex -s flushcomma.ist -o mydoc.ind mydoc.idx
```

If you are not a command line person, you can use Arara. Put these lines at the top of your `mydoc.tex`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { style: flushcomma.ist }
% arara: pdflatex
```

and define the `\myfill` command:

```
\def\myfill{\hfill\nopagebreak}
```

Full MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { style: flushcomma.ist }
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{doc}
\IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\def\myfill{\hfill\nopagebreak}
\begin{document}
Some text \index{Spread out} \index{\textbackslash efill}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

#### If you want that in *all* entries (questionable way):

Then you have to somehow change the macro that writes the contents of the `\index` command to the `.idx` file. If you don't have `hyperref` loaded you can put this definition in your preamble:

```
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1a|myfill}{\thepage}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}%
```

if you load `hyperref`, however, then you can use this one:

```
\def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1|myfill|\\}%
```

Full MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{doc}
\IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}
\usepackage{makeidx}

%% Without hyperref
% \makeatletter
% \def\@wrindex#1{%
%    \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
%       {\string\indexentry{#1a|myfill}{\thepage}}%
%  \endgroup
%  \@esphack}%
% \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% With hyperref
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1|myfill|\\}%
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeindex
\def\myfill{\hfill\nopagebreak}
\begin{document}
Some text \index{Spread out} \index{\textbackslash efill}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

#### If you want that in only a few entries:

Then, as the very next thing that the `makeindex` program writes after the index entry is the `,` then you can define the `\myfill` command like this:

```
\def\myfill#1{#1\hfill\nopagebreak}
```

the command will take an argument, the comma, and will put it behind the `\hfill` in the entries where you use it. Make sure that it is the very last thing you pass to the `\index` command, or it won't work.

Full MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{doc}
\IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\def\myfill#1{#1\hfill\nopagebreak}
\begin{document}
Some text \index{Spread out} \index{\textbackslash efill\myfill}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```